# How do I exec a sproc to get either the first or second select statement in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I have two queries being returned by my sproc. I want to be able to select one of them for one thing, and select the other one in another query.

sp_mysproc has two select statements being returned:

```
select * from Orders where customerid = @customerid
select * from Customer where customerid = @customerid
```

How can I execute sp_mysproc to get either of these two queries? Do I need to add  to end ';1' or ';2'?

Comment: Be easier/better to just create 2 separate stored procedures and call the one you need.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: By convention, you should **not** use a `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures - Microsoft reserves that prefix, and odd things could happen if you do

Comment: @Marc / the only "odd" thing is a slight penalty for searching first in master.dbo rather than the current database/schema

Comment: @richard - if they somehow create it in `master` it will also get deleted on detach/reattach or server restart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should really use two separate stored procs as Martin suggested.

trying to use one function/stored proc to do two different things is just making life more difficult than it has to be.

but if you really want to, and please don't, take a look at passing in a parameter to tell which query your want and using an if statement to select the appropriate query.

but seriously, please just break it up into two stored procs. I've seen plenty of devs try to do this and it just ends up making life for them more complicated later on down the road.

Here would be quick and dirty example of using if statements to select the individual queries...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spMySproc]
(
    @CustomerID INT,
    @Table VARCHAR(10)
)
AS
BEGIN
    IF @Table = 'Orders'
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM [Orders] WHERE [CustomerID]=@CustomerID
    END
    IF @Table = 'Customer'
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM [Customer] WHERE [CustomerID]=@CustomerID
    END
END
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure if this was the best way or not.  I did think I saw some code that used a ;1 or ;2 at the end to choose which query to pull during an exec, but i don't know if it was sql2000 or .net.

Comment: @Marc - That syntax is "numbered stored procedures". [They are deprecated](http://jagbarcelo.blogspot.com/2006/09/numbered-stored-procedures-will-be.html) and provide no advantage over just creating 2 different sensibly named stored procedures!